# How do i make preprocessor macros evaluate code before compilation

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

i'm using macros to define static size for some arrays in my code, i have defined a config macro variable at the top of my code and some macro variables depend on said macro variable. i can make a function that takes that value and returns the required size of the array but that would execute in runtime and i'll need to use VLAs.
example below shows macro for SIZE of a number (with no repeating digits) and whether that number can begin with a zero ("0123" vs "1234").

code to calculate LIMIT in runtime:

```c
int limit(int size, int npz){
    l = npz ? 9 : 10;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        l *= 10 - i;
    return l;
}
```

i manually calculated the amount of said numbers for all values. is there a work around?

```c
#define SIZE 4 // 1 .. 10
#define NO_PADDING_ZERO 1 // 1 | 0
#if NO_PADDING_ZERO
    #if SIZE == 1
        #define LIMIT 9
    #elif SIZE == 2
        #define LIMIT 81
    #elif SIZE == 3
        #define LIMIT 648
    #elif SIZE == 4
        #define LIMIT 4536
    #elif SIZE == 5
        #define LIMIT 27216
    #elif SIZE == 6
        #define LIMIT 136080
    #elif SIZE == 7
        #define LIMIT 544320
    #elif SIZE == 8
        #define LIMIT 1632960
    #else
        #define LIMIT 3265920
    #endif
#else
    #if SIZE == 1
        #define LIMIT 10
    #elif SIZE == 2
        #define LIMIT 90
    #elif SIZE == 3
        #define LIMIT 720
    #elif SIZE == 4
        #define LIMIT 5040
    #elif SIZE == 5
        #define LIMIT 30240
    #elif SIZE == 6
        #define LIMIT 151200
    #elif SIZE == 7
        #define LIMIT 604800
    #elif SIZE == 8
        #define LIMIT 1814400
    #else
        #define LIMIT 3628800
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: What is the formula for `LIMIT`?  I can't figure out the pattern and I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Oh, the first sequence seems to be 9, 9*9, 9*9*8, 9*9*8*7, 9*9*8*7*6, etc.  The second sequence is larger by a factor of 10/9.

Comment: updated with runtime code.

Comment: If you need a more powerful preprocessor, and you are crazy enough, you can generate the C code with PHP; that is, instead of the usual application of PHP living alongside HTML to output HTML, you can have PHP living alongside C to output C.

Comment: The C preprocessor doesn't seem to be powerful enough to do this in a simpler way.  I'd suggest just using the code you have right now, or allocating the array at run time with `malloc` after computing the size, or just defining `LIMIT` to always be 3628800 if you don't mind using some extra memory.

Comment: Switch to C++ and use constexpr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this some kind of the factorial?

```
(10 - NO_PADDING_ZERO) * 9 * 8 * ... * (10 - LIMIT)
```

You can use this in the loop expression in a macro or an inline function and the optimizing compiler will compute it at compile time.

```
#include <bool.h>

inline int limit(int size, bool npz){
    int l = 10 - npz;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        l *= 10 - i;
    return l;
}

#define LIMIT (limit(SIZE, NO_PADDING_ZERO))
```

If you wish you may define a precomputed array and use

```
#define LIMIT (array[SIZE][NO_PADDING_ZERO])
```

Comment: this will compile?

Comment: This will not. But you shown the function, just declare it inline.

Comment: wouldn't that would cause arrays defined by the output to be VLAs?

Comment: What and where array?

Comment: there is an array in my code that contains all counted numbers declared `int universe[LIMIT];`.

Comment: Hundred words in the question could be replaced with a small code of the desired solution.

Comment: this seems to do the trick, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

#### The workaround could be to *generate* C code from something else.

Consider learning more, using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or your own C code generator (perhaps using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) and in some simple cases [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)).

Observe that on Linux or POSIX, you could generate C code, compile it as a plugin, and [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that plugin. For a useless example, see [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c). For useful (but obsolete) example, see my old [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/MELT-Starynkevitch-DSL2011.pdf).

Another approach ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) specific) might be to extend your compiler with [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). See [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/).

You can also generate machine code (in your program) using [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) or (in C++) [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/). Then read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) answer.

Read some books by [Jacques Pitrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat) explaining that metaprogramming approach (reused in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/))

The concepts related to [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) are relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. but 237K's answer is what i was looking for. will sure be digging into what you suggested.